# How do I figure out the determinants of slow page load times?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, loading, topojson

I have the following two custom Google maps - [the hockey map](http://www.the10and3.com/hockey.htm) and [the languages map](http://www.the10and3.com/hockey.htm) - that were built for a [data blog](http://www.the10and3.com) that I am currently working on.

If you visit either link, you will see that the load times are very slow (5-15 seconds depending on the browser and your Internet connection). I'm not sure if these load times are inherent to using Google Maps to build a map with this level of complexity or if I'm doing something that can be fixed. I'm not familiar at all with diagnosing this sort of problem so any suggestions as to where to start would be appreciated.

**FYI**

The maps were built using a combination of the following tools:

- HTML+CSS+JavaScript
- Google Maps + TopoJSON
- [QGIS](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/slider/)
- [Points2Polygons](https://github.com/gabrielflorit/points2polygons/)

**EDIT**

I've been told by a friend that he thinks the issue is related to Google's processing of the JSON data, which may be out of my control. Can anyone confirm that?

Comment: Check out http://jsperf.com/ if you need a tool for benchmarking different JS snippets.

Comment: @JeromyFrench Thanks for this but this seems to be useful for comparing different JS snippets. How would I use it in my case?

Comment: I interpret "slow page load" to include JavaScript execution time (as opposed to just asset transmission time). So, if the page still "feels" sluggish after you resolve your asset loading issues, jsperf will help you identify and resolve JS performance bottlenecks.

Answer (score 1):

The main browsers (firefox / chrome) have modules/extensions or developper mode who can inspect the loading time and give you more information about this.

Comment: Thanks. Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: If you use firefox, Firebug can give you usefull informations.

Comment: But what do I actually do with Firebug? What do I want to turn on?

Comment: For Chrome's dev tools (which are developer gold), check out https://developer.chrome.com/devtools